# Записать значения в массив по индексу assembler (fasm)

Tags: массивы, ассемблер, fasm

Как мне заполнить массив длинной 10 элементами равными их индексу, т.е. в первой ячейке должен быть 0, во второй 1 и т.д, иными словами `array[i]=i`. Я написал код, но он почему-то не работает.

```
format PE GUI 5.0
include 'C:\fasm\INCLUDE\win32a.inc'
entry start

section '.data' data readable writeable

Caption db 'Ответ к задаче',0
fmt db "result = %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",0 ; строка форматирования
buf rb 256 ; буфер под строку-результат
array dd -1, -3, -2, 4, 5, 9, 13, -13, 2, 3
result dd 10 dup(0)
size = $-result
tmp dw 0
i dd 0
j dd 0
n dd 0

section '.code' readable executable

start:

mov di, size/4
mov si, 0

for1:
cmp si, di
jge _exit

inc si
mov eax, [i]
mov [result+4*i], eax
inc [i]


jmp for1


_exit:



cinvoke wsprintf, buf, fmt, [i], [result+4], [result+4*2], [result+4*3], [result+4*4], [result+4*5], [result+4*6], [result+4*7], [result+4*8], [result+4*9] ; cinvoke т.к. соглашение cdecl
invoke MessageBox,0,buf,Caption,MB_OK

section '.idata' import data readable writeable

library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL', user32,'USER32.DLL' 
include 'C:\fasm\INCLUDE\API\kernel32.inc'
include 'C:\fasm\INCLUDE\API\user32.inc'
```

Сам код компилируется и запускается, но сразу же закрывается. В языках выского уровня мне наверняка выдало бы какой-нибудь эксепшн, и я так подозреваю это из-за строчки `mov [resul+4*i], eax`. Как это можно исправить чтоб работало? Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень вам признателен.

Comment: В чём проблема пройтись отладчиком и узнать что не работает?

Answer (score 1):

Эта строка работает не так как вы думаете: `[result+4*i]` - это `адрес переменной result + 4 * адрес переменной i` (не ее значение). Получается обращение куда-то по какому-то адресу, явно за границами массива `result`. Вам нужно вместо `i` использовать какой-нибудь регистр.

Можно использовать `si` (`esi`), тем более что он и так у вас работает счетчиком цикла:

```
    mov edi, size/4
    mov esi, 0
    
for1:
    cmp esi, edi
    jge _exit

    mov [result+4*esi], esi
    inc esi

    jmp for1

_exit:
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, адресовать массив через непосредсвенный операнд - не лучшая идея. Для таких случаев предусмотрен регистр EBX, который так и называется "Регистр базы". Тогда инструкция внутри цикла сокращается на 4-байта в х32, и на целых 8-байт в х64. Инженеры Intel ввели базово-индексную адресацию с учётом того (см.байт SIB в формате команд, Scale-Index-Base), что декодер инструкций процессора читает из кеша L1(inst) макс.по 16-байт, и при двух непосредственных операндах могут возникнуть случаи, когда длина инструкции может выйти за этот предел (особенно в инструкциях SIMD).

Поэтому практичней поместить адрес массива `Result` в регистр EBX, и адресовать через него. Можно вообще сократить инструкцию записи в массив до 1-байта, если использовать STOSD с адресацией `Result` через EDI. Вот несколько примеров одного действия, с результатом в отладчике. Оптимизация подобного рода конечно-же не играет роли конкретного в данном случае, но если столкнуться с большими\вложенными циклами, то выигрыш по времени будет на лицо:

```
.code
start:   dw     0x9090              ;// дубль-NOP

         mov    [result+4*esi],0    ;// два непосредственных операнда!

         dw     0x9090
         mov    ecx,10              ;// длина массива
         xor    esi,esi             ;// индекс
@@:      mov    [result+4*esi],esi  ;// запись в массив по индексу
         inc    esi
         loop   @b

         dw     0x9090
         mov    ecx,10
         xor    esi,esi
         mov    ebx,result          ;// база в EBX
@@:      mov    [ebx+4*esi],esi     ;//<--- запись в массив
         inc    esi
         loop   @b

         dw     0x9090
         mov    edi,result          ;// приёмник для STOSD
         xor    eax,eax             ;// значение для записи (индекс)
@@:      stosd                      ;//<---- запись в массив
         inc    eax                 ;// сл.инднекс..
         cmp    al,10               ;// проверить на макс
         jne    @b                  ;// повторить, если меньше
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]